# Remove HTML tag from string

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Remove all HTML tags like `&nbsp;`or `<p>` from string. I used below code but it's not working.

```
var content = "<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;test result</p><br/>"; // My String

content.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: String.CompareOptions.regularExpression, range: nil)
```

but it does not remove all HTML tags from string.

Comment: And what's the result? Is "&nbsp;" really part of the tag? In you regex, where does it appear? That's supposed to be a space.

Comment: @Larme, I doubt the OP wrote the regex - I suspect that he picked it up as a piece of magic code that "removes HTML tags"...

Comment: @Grimxn I don't doubt that. But I think that comments area is a good place to point out where could be the issue, giving hints, ideas, and it's up to the author too do some research on its end.

Answer (score 21):

```
var content = "<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;test result</p><br/>"; // My String

let a = content.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: String.CompareOptions.regularExpression, range: nil)
```

a will be: `&nbsp;&nbsp;test result`

```
let b = a.replacingOccurrences(of: "&[^;]+;", with: "", options: String.CompareOptions.regularExpression, range: nil)
```

b  will now be: `test result`

This will also take care of `&lt;` and so on. There is no magic. Find out what you need and then write the proper RegEx.

Answer (score 15):

**Swift 4 tested**: Removes all HTML tags and decodes entities

Provides more stable result

```
extension String {
    public var withoutHtml: String {
        guard let data = self.data(using: .utf8) else {
            return self
        }

        let options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey: Any] = [
            .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
            .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
        ]

        guard let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: options, documentAttributes: nil) else {
            return self
        }

        return attributedString.string
    }
}
```

Comment: Beware. There are known issues with this approach. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/115405

Answer (score 13):

For this we can use

```
extension String {
    var withoutHtmlTags: String {
    return self.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: 
    .regularExpression, range: nil).replacingOccurrences(of: "&[^;]+;", with: 
    "", options:.regularExpression, range: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**Use Following Extension tested on Playground in Swift 3.0**

```
extension String {
    var withoutHtmlTags: String {
      return self.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
let result = "<strong>HTML</strong> Tags <em>Contain</em> <img /> <a href=\"\">String</a>".withoutHtmlTags
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to build an attributed string:

```
 let data = content.data(using: .utf8)
 let options = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType] as [String : Any]
 let attrStr = try NSAttributedString(data:data!, options:options ,documentAttributes:nil)
 content = attrStr.string
```

Answer (score 2):

I used extensions. Extended String and Data. First I convert the HTML to `NSAttributedString` and then convert to a plain `String`.

```
extension String {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        return Data(utf8).htmlToAttributedString
    }

    var htmlToString: String {
        return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}

extension Data {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        // Converts html to a formatted string.
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: self, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("error:", error)
            return nil
        }
    }
    var htmlToString: String {
        return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let html = "<div><p>Example</p></div>"
html.htmlToString() //returns example
```

Answer (score 1):

add extension

```
extension String {

   func removeHTMLTag() -> String {

       return self.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: String.CompareOptions.regularExpression, range: nil)

    }

}
```

and use this

```
let htmlString : String = "<div> <p>I cannot understand </p> </div>"

htmlString.removeHTMLTag() // I cannot understand
```